# OmniAuth:Builder#call getting called on every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

So is a rails/omniauth gem question. I'm using OmniAuth in a pretty vanilla way, just the basic gem install, then add my facebook and twitter secret keys for my app, and then create an omni auth controller with a log in method and in the routes I put `match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'omniauth#login', via: [:get, :post, :put, :delete]`.
Basically what every other omniauth user does.

My question is, when I started to analyze the performance of my app on new relic, I noticed that every single request to my app (including all the ones that aren't related to omniauth at all) are taking about ~13ms to go through OmniAuthBuilder:call.
I would like to avoid this if possible since my app is an internal API and adding 10ms to every request slows down all of my api calls.
I've looked at the source code for OmniAuth::Builder#call and it seems to be just passing the call along to the app, but I'm not totally sure why that is happening.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to skip that step for most of my requests? I know it's a tough question but Stack has always been helpful in the past :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was seeing this in New Relic because OmniAuth::Builder was the last rack app on the stack. So really it was taking 13 ms to go through all the rack apps.